# Sending class objects between java client and php server

Tags: java, php, android

We have java client on Android and php as server side.
Our problem is sending some class object between client and server. Object contains some simple data types(like integer or string) and fields of another class(coordinates x,y for example).
What is the best way to implement it? 
Sending through json? xml? maybe smth like hessian?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please use care when selecting tags.  They aren't keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words as your question title doesn't help categorize the question.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you cannot send the objects, you can only send data. Why not use JSON? It is known to work.

Comment: in php we can serialize objects for saving them(between sessions, for example) and then unserialize. 
can we send serializabled objects between two programming languages, provided that we have the same classes in php and java(is it real at all?)?

Comment: You cannot do that. PHP serializes into a special format, only PHP can deserialize. If you search around, maybe you find somebody who wrote a Java Library to serialize and deserialize into PHPs serialize function format. Better you go with JSON, as Sven mentioned. Or use Googles protobuf.